# How to create a Windows executable with FileVersion containing commas

Tags: .net, version, versioning, executable

Is there a way in .NET to create an executable file where FileVersion value has commas?

Ex: 4,4,3

I want commas instead of dots as the delimiter.  How can I do it?

Alternately, is there any resource hacker tool available which allows this? I tried ResourceHacker but it converts commas to dots.

Comment: I'm just asking myself. Why?

Comment: I have a specific requirement.

Comment: Here's hoping this impossible requirement isn't a deal breaker for you!

Comment: I want to change the delimiter from dot to comma. I have seen this before in some files. I think its not impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, the FileVersion field is stored as a 64-bit integer, so whether you use a dot or a comma in the presentation is up to you - or whichever tool is displaying the information. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT: to clarify, there is no way to store the version with commas, because it's not stored as a string, only as the four individual integers cobbled together as one 64-bit integer.

Comment: This only specifies how version is being stored. It doesn't specify delimiter used to separate them. I am trying to find out how can i change to delimeter from dot to comma

Comment: That's the point, it *doesn't* store the delimiter. It only stores the version.

Comment: There are several applications which have comma in FileVersion . Ex: cisco anyconnect executable vpncli.exe has it. Others include jre (jabswitch.exe)

Comment: Ah, you probably mean the free-form string field, then. You'll have to add a `VALUE "FileVersion", "1,2,3,4"` in one of the localised `StringFileInfo` blocks to set that instead of the `FILEVERSION` in the global scope. There's an example for that in that same link above.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can't change how they're stored, but you can store how you might visualize them in your own application.

Comment: Please suggest how can I do that?

Comment: I just mean, you can't change the format, but if you have your own app, just replace the '.' with ','